# Why the following error occurs only in PGSQL and not in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

> must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I am doing inner join between two tables and used one of the foreign key in base table within group by and the above error was thrown. But it works fine in MYSQL

Comment: must add some code, must add sample data, must read the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Because MySQL for some god-forsaken reason allows for the absence of non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` clause.  You should never leave out a column from a `GROUP BY` that isn't aggregated, as it will lead to weird results in MySQL, and (rightfully) to an error in every other DBMS.

Comment: Note that newer MySQL versions are stricter. (I.e. lots of incompatible MySQL applications out there...)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are speaking about mysql < 5.7 this is a non standard feature in mysql which they did away with mysql 5.7

Please see : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

> **sqlmode_only_full_group_by**
>   Reject queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER
>   BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the
>   GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on (uniquely determined
>   by) GROUP BY columns.
>
> As of MySQL 5.7.5, the default SQL mode includes ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.
>   (Before 5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and
>   ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default. For a description of
>   pre-5.7.5 behavior, see the MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual.)